# To find unknown rows in a unitary matrix

Tags: matrices, unitary-matrices

The problem is to find a unitary matrix A whose first row is a multiple of

a) $(1,1,-i)$ and

b) $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{i}{2},\frac{(1-i)}{2}\right)$

Now the first part of a is easy because the rows have to form an Orthonormal set. Thus one gets the usual orthonormalization. However I am stuck as to what to do next, as I am getting just a bunch of equations applying the fact that the dot product has to be zero, especially in part b of the problem.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Does this really require MathJax ?? There is not many symbols in the body of the text.

Comment: Looks terrible: b.(1/2,i/2,(1-i)2 ... I am stuck reading. I would think the equations are easy, but I don't dare to ask for your equations - without MathJax. So do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To complete a unit row $u_1=(u_{11},u_{12},u_{13})$ with $(u_{11},u_{12})\ne 0\ne u_{13}$  to a unitary matrix, we can choose a row $u_2$ proportional to $(\overline{u_{12}},-\overline{u_{11}},0)$ and a row $u_3$ proportional to $\left(u_{11},u_{12},-\frac{|u_{11}|^2+|u_{21}|^2}{\overline{u_{31}}}\right)$.
This approach yields matrices
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{-i}{\sqrt{3}} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{2i}{\sqrt{6}} 
\end{pmatrix}\mbox{ and }
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{i}{2} & \frac{1-i}{2} \\
\frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{i}{2} & \frac{-1+i}{2} 
\end{pmatrix},
$$
for a) and b), respectively.

Comment: Hi , what is the reasoning behind the procedure?? I took the cross product of 2 complex vectors , is that allowed??

Comment: @herashefat As you can see, I tried to construct row with simple form. I also tried to obtain the last row as a cross product of two complex vectors via Mathcad, but it failed. But I had the second row orthogonal to the first, so I used this property to construct the last row instead.